# Sonarcube credentials in docker container

Tags: docker, sonarqube

How do i set my own sonarcube credentials while building in docker container. By default t takes admin:admin credentials.
I am wondering is there any sonar cli which i can righ tin dockerfile.
Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You can use `api/users/create`web service to create a new user, once the web server is started, but not before.